# How to implement BTCQuote in OS x app

Tags: swift, macos, firebase, xcode7

I am new developer and I would like to know how to implement BTCQuote ticker in my app. How to make my label show bitcoin value, and how to make it auto-updating.

Thank you

Comment: My app would show ammount in USD on how much is one bitcoin worth. It would update automaticaly every minute or less.

Comment: I recommend you spend some time going through the Firebase documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/. It'll teach you more than asking this incredibly open question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to start, if you are using firebase, build a basic firebase app. Look at the javascript code provided by BTCQuote here;

https://github.com/firebase/btcquote/blob/master/src/btcquote-widget.js

and add their code to get the data. You can modify it to fit the needs of your app.

If you are not using firebase, you can build a standard OS X app with swift and then use javascriptcore. There is an intro here;

http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/

and a small example here;

http://k33g.github.io/2014/06/10/SWIFT-01.html

You can use the javascriptcore to execute the example code provided by BTCQuote or a modified version.

Comment: What if im not using firebase, and how to implement javascript with swift?